# AWS Event Bridge DLQ configuration using Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dead-letter, aws-event-bridge

The serverless framework docs of AWS Event Bridge [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/event-bridge/) do not mention how to set up a dead letter queue and retry attempts. I was hoping for the configuration of serverless.yml would look something like below but it did not work.

```
myLambda:
    handler:  ./src/functions/myLambda
    events:
      - eventBridge:
          eventBus: arn:aws:events:region:accountID:event-bus/busname
          deadLetterConfig: 
            arn: arn:aws:sqs:region:accountID:sqs-name
          pattern:
            source: 
              - ${self:custom.sourceNameForEventBus}
```

These properties can be added after the deployment manually as shown below. But I want to add it using the framework else if there is a way to manipulate this using CloudFormation?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this functionality has been released since the original question was asked but it is quite simple and [documented](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/event-bridge#adding-a-retry-policy-to-an-event-rule).

```
functions:
  myFunction:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - eventBridge:
          eventBus: custom-saas-events
          pattern:
            source:
              - saas.external
          deadLetterQueueArn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - QueueName
              - Arn
          retryPolicy:
            maximumEventAge: 3600
            maximumRetryAttempts: 3
```